# How to get rid of square bracket when converting sql data to json file

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm converting SQL data into JSON file and when I get JSON file it starts with square brackets [], like an array how do I get rid of that.

```
  let sqlQuery = "select * from dbo.cust where name like 'aa%' AND surname like 'a%' AND branch='bsmtr';";
       sqlRequest.query(sqlQuery, function (err, data) {
         if(err) console.log(err) 
         console.log(data);
       
         fs.writeFile(`json_files/${fileName}.json`, JSON.stringify(data.recordset), err => err && console.log(err));
```

---JSON FILE IM GETTING------

```
 [
        {
            "rowno": 294680503,
            "no_": 122838,
            "branch": "bsmtr",
            "benefit": "regular",
            "title": "",
            "primary_": "yes",
            "primmem": 122838,
            "primbr": "bsmtr",
            "surname": "Arnett",
            "name": "Aaron",
            "bname2": "",
            "midname": "C",
            "usual": "",
            "status": "closed",
            "pb": 1013,
            "signer": "yes",
            "sdate": "2003",
    }
    ]
```

Comment: and what's wrong with that ? that's part of json string

Comment: Your query returns an array of object so you have the brackets. If there is always 1 object returned from your query, you can get the first elements in the array like `data.recordset[0]`